# Magento 2 Category Page Show Error Casue of SKU has " conflict with JS

Tags: magento2

Bellow Is the code where SKU has the issue, Let me know How to fix this issue. I didn't find any code online to fix it. Magento 2 Category Page Show Error Casue of SKU has " conflict with JS.

```
 {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {
                    "product_sku": "8" Tested Product "
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

$_item replace with you $product or $_product.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
        "catalogAddToCart": {
            "product_sku": "<?php echo  /* @NoEscape */ 
                    $_item->getSku() ?>"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

hope this help you. : thankx